# need to get classes from css

Tags: java, css, file-io

I am new to java i want to store all class names(only name) of particular css file in hashmap or vector please help me i want to store BODY,.title, .surveyinstruct,.parthdr in hashmap

e.g

```
  BODY{
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #cccccc;
font-size: medium;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: black;
background-image: url(images/BLACKbody_whitemarble.jpg);
}
.title{
font-family: sans-serif;
color: Navy;
font-size: medium;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: Transparent;
border: no;
}
.surveyinstruct{
font-family: Arial;
color: black;
font-size: small;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
background-color: Transparent;
border: no;
}
.parthdr{
color: Navy;
font-size: x-small;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #999999;
border: no;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

now i have to store   BODY,.title,.surveyinstruct ,.parthdr in hashmap or vector
 i.e hashmap should contain all class names which i can use for further work
                thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/). It's not perfect and that simple, but it gives you a lot more...

```
public Map<String, CSSStyleRule> parseCSS() throws IOException {
    Map<String, CSSStyleRule> rules = new HashMap<String, CSSStyleRule>();

    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader("bootstrap.css"));
    CSSStyleSheet styleSheet = new CSSOMParser().parseStyleSheet(inputSource, null, null);

    CSSRuleList ruleList = styleSheet.getCssRules();
    for (int i = 0; i < ruleList.getLength(); i++) {
        CSSRule rule = ruleList.item(i);
        if (rule.getType() == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE) {
            CSSStyleRule styleRule = (CSSStyleRule) rule;
            rules.put(styleRule.getSelectorText(), styleRule);
        }
    }

    return rules;
}
```

Comment: CSSParser does not support CSS3, e.g. CSS3 media query, CSS3 selectors and browser-specific selectors like @-webkit-keyframes. So beware. Otherwise it is good..!!

Comment: I think that limitation came from [SAC](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/) and it was under development a while ago. Not sure if it is at this moment...

Comment: IT'S GIVING ERROR ON CSSOMParser()

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek thank u very much code is working fine only one question jar used for cssparser is open source or not?

Comment: Yes, it's Open Source - LGPL. No problem to use it even in commercial product.

Comment: So is it working or not? Please do accept the answer if it does...

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek when i print styleRule in given example it doesn't take semicolon to last part  e.g                                      .sunny { font-family: monospace; color: red; font-size: xx-small; font-style: italic;    font-weight: bold; background-color: Transparent; border: no } if u look at border:no there is no semicolon at end of border so why it is happening